# in R, functions applied to vectors vs scalars in data.table

Tags: r

I want to check my understanding of data.table behavior, because I find myself trying to guess how R will behave when using functions on the RHS of the `:=` operator.

Any nuance to my observations is welcome (as well as comments on how this relates to data.table vs. data.frame).

Mostly, I want to figure out how to know when `:=` used with functions will take references to a column in data.table (on the RHS) as a vector of every value in the column versus simply applying the function by row to each value.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = c(-100,-50,0,50,100))

dt[,y := max(0,x)]
dt[,z := abs(x)]
dt[,sd := sd(x)]
```

Here, `min` seems to turn 0 and the vector of all x values into a single vector, then runs on that new vector. More to the point, it seems to take every value in column x, not just the value of x on a given row.

On the other hand, `abs` returns just the absolute value of the x for that row.

And then `sd` takes the entire column x as the argument (rather than applying by row).

Do I just have to dig into the documentation for a function to see if it takes an atomic argument vs a vector argument, and assume that if the function takes a vector, it will apply to the entire column (and not apply to each row)? Is that the best way I can do this?

Comment: I am not sure what the exact question is. I think you just have to know your functions. This seems to be the issue rather than data.frame or data.table.

Comment: R has `max` and `pmax` for scalar and vector output respectively.

Comment: *"Do I just have to dig into the documentation for a function to see if it takes an atomic argument vs a vector argument,"* I mean, I don't mean to be glib but yeah. One of the first things you should look at when you use an unfamiliar function is what types of arguments it expects. The documentation is a good place to look.

Comment: *"...and assume that if the function takes a vector, it will apply to the entire column (and not apply to each row)"* columns are vectors. A data frame is a list of vectors that all happen to be the same length and we call them columns. The function sees the input vector, the function itself doesn't know if the vector is in a data frame or not, the behavior of the function will be the same either way. In your question you seem to be very focused on the type of input, but functions can all take the same type of input and have different outputs...

Comment: ...Some functions operate element-wise and return a vector of the same length as the input (`abs`, `+`, `pmax`, `log`...), other functions condense (aggregate) the input down to a single returned value (`mean`, `max`, `sd`, ...). Some functions do other things (`quantile` returns a vector with as many quantiles as you ask for, `lm` returns a linear model, `c()` concatenates). It's not whether the input is a vector or not, or a column in a data frame or not, it's *what the function is designed to do* that matters. And the documentation is where that should be described.